# quaestion to solution of the Laplace's Equation $u_{tt}+u_{xx}=0$ using method of separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

**Looking for some explanation to the use of boundary conditions** 



I have the Laplace's Equation  $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0, \quad 0<x<L, 0<y<H$$
with boundary conditions $$u(0,y)=0, \ u(L,y)=0, \ u(x,0)=f(x), \ u(x,H)=0$$

I am analyzing the solution from the textbook (http://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/pde1/PDEbook/PDE_Main.pdf  p.49) and have a question to the second ODE $$Y''-\lambda Y=0$$
The solution to the resulting quadratic equation depends on $\lambda$ so there will be three cases. Using the two conditions $Y(0)=0$ and $Y(H)=0$ I understand that the case 2 ($\lambda=0$) and case 3 ($\lambda<0$) give the trivial solution. I assume that the Y(0)=0 condition was used as first in analysis for the two cases.

Question: 
Applying the Y(0)=0 condition to the first case should get the trivial solution either, shouldn't it? **why don't we get the trivial solution for the case 1 either ($\lambda>0$)?**

I mean
$$Y(y)=c_1 e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} y} + c_2 e^{\sqrt{\lambda} y}$$
$$Y(0)=c_1  + c_2=0$$
$$c2=-c1$$
$$Y(H)=c_1 e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} H} - c_1 e^{\sqrt{\lambda} H} =0$$ 
$$0=c_1(e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} H} - e^{\sqrt{\lambda} H})$$
as $H>0$ then $(e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} H} - e^{\sqrt{\lambda} H})<0$ therefore $\quad c_1 = 0 \quad$ thus  $\quad c_2 = 0 \quad$ trivial solution again

**UPDATE
 



QUESTION:




I don't understand why thy $Y(0)=0$ can not be used in the stated problem as opposed to the below example where the condition can be used.  Could anybody help to understand this difference please.


$$Y''+ \lambda Y=0$$
$$0<x<L, \ 0<y<H$$
$$\ u(x,0)=u(x,H)=0, \ u(L,y)=0, \ u(0,y)=v$$**

Comment: You don't have the boundary condition $Y(0)=0$, you have the condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$, which you account for on the next page.

Comment: @ Awegyan are the $u(0,y)=0$ and $u(x,0)=0$ conditions not implying that $u(0,0)=0$ therefore $Y(0)=0$?

Comment: You don't have the condition $u(x,0)=0$, you have $u(x,0)=f(x)$.  If you did have $u(x,0)=0$ then you are right, you will get the trivial solution.

Comment: @ Awegyan I had a look at similar problem with slightly different conditions $$Y''+ \lambda Y=0$$ $$0<x<L, \ 0<y<H$$ $$\ u(x,0)=u(x,H)=0, \ u(L,y)=0, \ u(0,y)=v$$  and there was the condition $Y(0)=Y(H)=0$  used. I am confused, why $Y(0)=0$ would be ok here?

Comment: That's because $u(x,0)=0$.

Comment: @ Awegyan I don't get it. In the first described problem there is $u(0,y)=0$, which would define all the points alongside y axis, wouldn't  include it (0,0)?  I don't understand why $u(x,0)=0$ includes (0,0) and u(0,y) not.

Comment: In the problem stated in your question, think about why the boundary conditions imply $X(0)=X(L)=0$.  Think about it hard, give it some time, then think about why the boundary conditions imply $Y(H)=0$, but **not** $Y(0)=0$.

Comment: @ Awegyan  boundary conditions for both problems can be pictured as rectangles. The only difference between those two problems is that 1 rectangle) the value of u on bottom side is defined by a function f(x) 2  rectangle) value of u on the left side is defined by a constant,  u on all other sides of both rectangles equals zero. Does the function vs constant play a role? I miss some concept here

Comment: Go back to the $1D$ heat equation (section $2.4.1$, where it explains why the boundary conditions imply that $X(0)=X(L)=0$, this may help.  If not, I would just say keep pushing forward until you can complete the problem using Fourier series.  After this, you will see that in fact, $u(0,0)=0$, but that isn't implied by your current boundary conditions.

Comment: @ Aweygan - can this condition be used only after the function is transformed to Fourier series?

Comment: What condition? In the process of implementing the condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ you find the Fourier series of $f(x)$.